# How to see today compiled object in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to find objects that were compiled today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `timestamp` column of [`dba_objects`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1155.htm#i1583352) is what you are after:

```
create table t(id integer);
create function f return integer as
  n integer;
begin
  select count(*) into n from t;
  return n;
end;
/

select status, timestamp from user_objects where object_name='F';
STATUS  TIMESTAMP           
------- ------------------- 
VALID   2011-09-05:11:01:52 

insert into t(id) values (1);
select f() from dual;             -- ***no recompile needed***

select status, timestamp from user_objects where object_name='F';
STATUS  TIMESTAMP           
------- ------------------- 
VALID   2011-09-05:11:01:52 

alter table t add dummy integer;  -- ***invalidates f()***

select status, timestamp from user_objects where object_name='F';
STATUS  TIMESTAMP           
------- ------------------- 
INVALID 2011-09-05:11:01:52 

select f() from dual;             -- ***forces recompile***
select status, timestamp from user_objects where object_name='F';
STATUS  TIMESTAMP           
------- ------------------- 
VALID   2011-09-05:11:01:53       -- ***note the different timestamp***
```

so to get all functions compiled today for example:

```
select * 
from dba_objects
where to_date(substr(timestamp,1,10), 'yyyy-mm-dd')>=trunc(sysdate)
      and object_type='FUNCTION';
```

--edit

it may be safer to use `last_ddl_time` instead (see @Alex's comment below), but the caveat is that `last_ddl_time` is also changed on grants and revokes.